# Efficient CIC Decimation Filter in C

Tags: filter-design, dsp-core, c, decimation, multirate

Does anyone have advice on efficient CIC Decimation filter implementation. I designed a basic 4th order CIC filter with a 64 decimation ratio in C (below).

I am currently testing this on a Sharc SC589 running at 450MHz, audio DMA's set at 48kHz output with 32 sample buffer giving me 300,000 cycles to play with in a callback routine. However, this filter is using ~310,000 cycles, hence I'm dropping frames.

To note, `pdmData` is two interleaved channels of pdm microphone data, i.e. evens bits = channel 1, odd bits = channel 2. Hence, each 32 bit word has 16 pdm bits per channel, so 4 words are needed for a decimation ratio of 64 in order to output a single sample at 48kHz. Only 1 channel is being decimated here.

I know I don't need 48kHz for mics, 16kHz would do and hence free up more cycles, but surely there is a better implementation of the this that could be run at 48kHz.

Thanks in advance.

```
#define CIC_ORDER   4
#define DECIM_FAC   64
#define NORM_RATIO  16777216 // DECIM_FAC^CIC_ORDER

// delay buffers
int32_t interBuff[CIC_ORDER] = {0};
int32_t combBuff[CIC_ORDER] = {0};

int main()
    float pcmData[32] = {0};
    for (uint32_t sampleIdx=0; sampleIdx<128; sampleIdx+=4)
    {
        // cic filtering
        pcmData[sampleIdx>>2] = cic_decimation_dual((int32_t*)pdmData+sampleIdx);
    }
}

float cic_decimation_dual(int32_t *dataIn)
{
    uint32_t orderIdx, sampleIdx;
    int32_t v0, bitIdx;

    for (sampleIdx = 0; sampleIdx < 4; sampleIdx++)
    {
        for (bitIdx = 31; bitIdx>0; bitIdx-=2)
        {
            // load bit value
            v0 = (dataIn[sampleIdx]>>bitIdx) & 0x1;

            // offset 0 bit to -1
            if (!v0)
            {
                v0 = -1;
            }

            // integrator stage
            for (orderIdx=0; orderIdx<CIC_ORDER; orderIdx++)
            {
                interBuff[orderIdx] += v0;
                v0 = interBuff[orderIdx];
            }
        }
    }

    // decimation/comb stage
    int32_t y, c0;

    c0 = interBuff[CIC_ORDER-1];
    for (orderIdx=0; orderIdx<CIC_ORDER; orderIdx++)
    {
        y = c0 - combBuff[orderIdx];
        combBuff[orderIdx] = c0;
        c0 = y;
    }

    return (float)y/NORM_RATIO;

}
```

Comment: I am not a specialist of the Sharc technology. Isn't there an FIR in its DSP function? You could leverage it

Comment: And why not try implement a chain of half band filter to start

Comment: I was thinking along that lines, but it was more that I wanted to test my own implementation. As a case of speaking too soon, I have just found an suggested implementation for a Blackfin running a 594MHz which says it use 560 cycles per channel, although for only 8 decimation ratio, but will try that. (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/EE-350rev1.pdf)

Comment: Only 4 samples?  Are you doing this in blocks of 4 samples?

Comment: Also, is this being run in the ARM portion of the SHArC?  or in one of the two SHArC parts?

Comment: more abstracted consideration: Why a CIC? CIC's are *awesome*, because the have finite impulse response properties while being made out of recursive elements that require no multiplications to be made, but you're on a DSP – which has multiply-accumulate units that are just as fast as just accumulating, so you're not actually winning through using a CIC, unless you really *want* the CIC for shape reasons (which is rare enough!).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - doing it in blocks of 4 samples at a time. Every 32 bit word of `dataIn` is 2 channels of interleaved data, hence for a decimation ratio of 64 I need 4 x 32 bit samples for every decimated output sample. This is on one of the Sharc cores.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - I think you are exactly right. Having managed to do a bit more digging, I came across the document I shared in my first comment above, which basically confirms this. Updating the code to their design, i.e. removing the for loop's iterating the over the order, increased efficiency by 3, so running at ~95,000 cycles. I think reducing the decimation ratio of the CIC filter and using half band FIR's is the only way to go, and a preferred implementation due to a better response around Nyquist and out of band noise reduction.

Comment: I'm not able to help you with your C programming, but the material at the following web page may be of some help in testing your multistage CIC processing: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1171.php

Comment: gdsp, it is my opinion that the C compiler for the SHArC does now and has always **sucked green donkey dick**.  It's a truly horrible compiler that generates truly horrible code for the SHArC DSP core.  I would expect that the C compiler for the ARM core is okay, as good (perhaps the same) as the C compiler is for other ARM products.  If you need to do efficient DSP using a SHArC, you should do it in SHArC asm, which is **not** a bad asm language (although some warts exists).  That said, your block size can be changed in the SPORT DMA to be longer than 4 samples.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, the moving-average filter, using recursion, has computation cost that is constant, **not** proportional to the length of the FIR.  But a problem that I have incurred with the recursive implementation of the moving-average FIR is that, using floating-point, you are not guaranteed to subtract from the accumulator *exactly* what you added $N$ samples prior.  That means a small rounding error is stuck in your accumulator and can never be removed.  That error can build up over time.  Recursive moving-average filters should **always** be done in fixed-point even if float is available.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson yeah, common problem. There's MAs that just reset every so-and-so many samples, to somewhat bound the accumulated error (which is only OK if your signal's dynamic range doesn't span too many powers of 2, otherwise, well, floating point addition is not your friend). Let me grad a link…

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson [link to C++ Moving Average with a reset every `num_iter`](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/v3.10.3.0/gr-blocks/lib/moving_average_impl.cc#L180-L188); `T` can be anything here, from `int8_t` to `float` or `complex<double>`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, what value is the accumulator reset to?  Does this moving-average run continuously?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson it's reset to a "freshly" done average of the last {length} samples, after a period of adding/subtracting the newest/oldest sample in the window.

Comment: (yes, that sometimes gives a transient. No, I'm not happy about that. I was just too lazy to implement something like a short window of "blending over" from old to new state. Should probably experiment with that. Also, should finally sit down and force someone to implement an adequate set of fixed point blocks for GNU Radio; most of what we do is float or complex float, and honestly, it sometimes stinks.)

Comment: I see how that could be efficiently done.  You would have the running moving-sum accumulator and then another accumulator that starts out at 0.  After $N$ samples, the two accumulators **should** be equal except for any residual roundoff error in the moving sum accumulator.  Then reset the moving sum to the *"fresh"* sum.  Okay, I get it.  And it's efficient because it's the cost of a moving sum plus another sum plus a decrementing countdown.  4 additions.  Worst case cost is the sample when you reset the moving-sum accumulator.

Comment: I have done this two different ways: convert to fixed point and do the moving sum with that (and convert the sum back to float).  And, in line with other Truncated IIR filters, I have done a floating-point moving sum with poles *slightly* inside the unit circle, instead of smack-dab on top of the unit circle.  There is an efficient way to do a *"Hann filter"* (an FIR that is the raised cosine like a Hann window) with TIIR.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson - thanks for that, really useful to know. It did surprise me that just removing the `for` loops had improved efficient by 3 times. I do need to dig into the assembly code and see what it's actually doing. I think the answer for now is just to reduce the decimation ratio of the CIC and use the FIR HW accelerator for the half band filters to decimate the final stages. I'm going to try this out, and test on the ARM core, see what I can get down to in the next few days.

Comment: @RichardLyons - it was actually your blog notes and book on CIC's that got me started, so thanks for that! It's great book btw.

Comment: @gdsp, send me an email to rbj@audioimagination.com and i can send you SHArC asm files showing how to set up the SPORTs and DMA for block processing.